# Accessing DateCreated and DateUpdated in Django/Python for Twilio

Tags: python, django, twilio

Here's my first post! I'm working with a python web app that is recording phone calls. I am able to access client.recordings.uri, but I'm not able to access recordings.datecreated or dateupdated in my code.

```
{% for recording in recordings %}
    <li><a href="{{ recording.uri }}.mp3">{{ recording.datecreated }} {{ recording.duration }} sec.</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

.uri and .duration are valid python attributes, does anyone know how to call the DateCreated attribute? Is it possible with the python module?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for recording in recordings %}
<li>
   <a href="{{ recording.uri }}.mp3">
    {{ recording.date_created }} {{ recording.duration }} sec.
  </a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

You'll need to add an underscore between datecreated. You can find a list of all attributes on the recording object [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/twilio-python/en/latest/api/rest/resources.html#recordings).